# Recursively looping through XML using XSL

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, recursion, xslt-1.0

I would like to translate the following XML file to a HTML page using XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Recursion.xsl"?>
<CompareResults hasChanges="true">
    <CompareItem name="Appel"  status="Identical">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="Abstract" model="false" baseline="false" status="Identical"/>
        </Properties>

        <CompareItem name="Banaan"  status="Identical">
            <Properties>
                <Property name="Abstract" model="false" baseline="false" status="Identical"/>
            </Properties>
        </CompareItem>

        <CompareItem name="Kiwi"  status="Identical">

            <CompareItem name="Peer"  status="Model only">
                <Properties>
                    <Property name="Abstract" model="false" baseline="false" status="Identical"/>
                    <Property name="Notes" model="PeerName" status="Model only"/>
                </Properties>
            </CompareItem>

            <Properties>
                <Property name="Abstract" model="false" baseline="false" status="Identical"/>
            </Properties>
        </CompareItem>
    </CompareItem>
</CompareResults>
```

The output should contain the elements that have the `@status` "Model only" and the whole path towards this element.
So, for this example:

- Appel
- Kiwi
- Peer
- Notes

My thought is that I should realize this by looping recursively through the XML, but the problem is that I can't figure out how templates can return a value. So, can anyone tell me if (and how) it is possible to return values or how to construct the XSL to comply to the required output?

This is my current XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/CompareResults">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CompareItem"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--CompareItem -->
<xsl:template match="CompareItem">

    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>

    <!-- Sub elements -->   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CompareItem"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In your example, only `Peer` and `Notes` have `status="Model only"`. Why do you expect `Appel` and `Kiwi` to be included in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am guessing (!) correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/CompareResults">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@name and descendant-or-self::*/@status='Model only']">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will output a `p` for every element that satisfies both:

1. it has a `name attribute`;
2. it or one of its descendants has a `status` attribute with the value of `"Model only"`.

resulting in:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Appel</p>
      <p>Kiwi</p>
      <p>Peer</p>
      <p>Notes</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi michael.hor257k, thanks for your reaction. I was not familiair with the descendant-or-self function so this will help a lot. The next thing I would like to do is to check if one of the sub elements contains the name 'notes' and the status 'Model Only'.  I tried to do this with the following code:<xsl:template match="*[@name and descendant-or-self::*/@status='Model only' and @name='Notes']"> But this resulted in the text 'notes' only, can you maybe tell me why I get this result?

Comment: @RoyvanMarrewijk If I understand this correctly, you want to do `<xsl:template match="*[@name and descendant-or-self::*[@status='Model only' and @name='Notes']]">`.

Comment: you are a genius!

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `@name` attribute values of all elements that have the `@status` attribute with the value "Model only" as an `ul` list can be done without recursion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />    

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@status = 'Model only']" mode="xx" />
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="xx" >
    <li><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></li>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result is:**

```
<html>
    <body>
         <ul>
            <li>Peer</li>
            <li>Notes</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

This does work well in a browser.

Comment: If you think the above works "*without recursion*", you are very much mistaken. You should also know that a leading`//` in a match pattern does not do anything. This is probably the source of your mistake. The situation would be slightly different if you did `<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@status = 'Model only']"/>` in the 1st template, and then made the 2nd template `match="*"`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Your suggestions for improvement are (often) welcome.  But this one didn't work without an additional `@mode="..."` attribute on the `<xsl:apply-templates...>` as well as on the `<xsl:template...>`. Anyway, I changed my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: No, mode is not necessary here. But you do need to remove the `<xsl:apply-templates />` instruction from the 2nd template. Otherwise you're still recursing over all nodes that are descendants of the nodes selected in the 1st template, and for no good reason. BTW, there's nothing wrong with recursion as such.